# Storing the new format of converted Image

Tags: shell, image-processing

I have a folder which is full of nifti images and I am writing my code in shell script. I want to read all images, and then convert each of them to jpg format with med2image library and then store it with the original name. Here is my code

```
for f in $(ls ./T1W/*.nii);  do med2image -i $f -d out -o  $f.jpg -s -1; done
```

However, I get the following error though I have an empty folder(its name is out)

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out//./T1W/sub-10235_T1w.nii-slice000.jpg'
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:
         for f in *.nii; do
         filename=${f%.*}
         med2image -i $filename.nii -d ./out -o $filename.jpg -s -1 
         done

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay, only need a colon after do, and path for out:

```
for f in $(ls ./T1W/*.nii); do : med2image -i $f -d ./out -o $f.jpg -s -1; done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does not work. I get the following error
                

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './out//./T1W/sub-10235_T1w.nii-slice000.jpg'

Comment: Test it with absolute paths.

Comment: `for f in $(ls /home/whatever/T1W/*.nii); do : med2image -i $f -d /home/whatever/out -o $f.jpg -s -1; done`

Comment: Absolute path is not working too! Look my first code, when I use f.jpg It converts all images to jpeg but name of all images are like f_slice1245.jpg, f_slice1246.jpg, f_slice1247 , ... . However, I want f to be name of the original image but not letter f. What should I do? I tried $f.jpg but it does not work too.